# How to make my layout with custom view scrollable? When I make a scroll view my root node, in stead of relativelayout, my view is not showing

Tags: android, view, scroll

Somehow my view just dissapears when I put the scrollview as the root node..
how to resolve this, I don't hvae a clue why this happens.

This is my xml, this is with the scrollview.
With this scrollview my custom view doesn't show on the screen.
When i remove the scrollview it does. I really don't know how to resolve this..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dennisText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="hierstaatdanstrakseenstoerenewsfeedendatsoortshitditdatallesstoermooiboyvriendje"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dennisText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="TextView" />"


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView0"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt2"
         />





    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drawView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/drawView2" />

    <com.TerraMare.DrawView2
        android:id="@+id/drawView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp" />




    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/Spinner3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/drawView2"
        android:maxWidth="150dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/draw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Spinner3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Spinner3"
        android:onClick="drawgraph"
        android:text="Teken Grafiek" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: You need to include some code, specifically you `XML` would be useful in this particular case. How else can anyone help you deduce the problem?

Comment: @aneal i added my xml, hope you can help me now!